# HTML 5 drag&drop

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

Different browsers show different content under cursor during dragging process. For example, try this http://jsfiddle.net/NRg2C/:

```
<span draggable="true">Draggable span</span>
<div draggable="true">Draggable div</div>
<table>
    <tr draggable="true">
        <td>Draggable row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

IE10 shows text in all cases. But Chrome shows text only for div. For span and table row it doesn't show anything. Is there a way to set this content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a browser quirk. The only way around it would be a Javascript drag/drop.